# Hypothesis testing critical value

Tags: normal-distribution, z-score

[image: H]

> -4.67 < a negative z $\iff$ 4.67 > a positive z

I don't understand this equation, please help me.

Comment: Well, in general when you're using a table of p-values for a z-test or a t-test, you are looking at a two-sided test, so you can look at both the positive and the negative side. But it's not really the cases that both statements are equivalent... Maybe give more context on your question or push back on the author of that slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Since the standard normal distribution is symmetric, with mean $\mu=0$, we have that:
$$P(z < -a) = P(z > a) \ .$$

Being symmetric with mean $\mu=0$ means that if you put a mirror on $0$, the image of the distribution on one side of the mirror (for instance, the positive side) is equal to the image of the distribution on the other side of the mirror (for instance, the negative side).